# Laravel 5.8 get a list of duplicates datas

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, duplicates

I'm looking for the most appropriate method to retrieve a list of duplicates in my database with laravel and eloquent.

Exemple of table records :

```
id : 1
artist_name : Jane Doe
track_name : The doe song

id : 2
artist_name : John Doe
track_name : A love song

id : 3
artist_name : Jane Doe
track_name : The doe song

id : 4
artist_name : John Doe
track_name : Happy

id : 5
artist_name : John Doe
track_name : Happy
```

Result expected (a list of all duplicates):

```
id : 1
artist_name : Jane Doe
track_name : The doe song

id : 3
artist_name : Jane Doe
track_name : The doe song

id : 4
artist_name : John Doe
track_name : Happy

id : 5
artist_name : John Doe
track_name : Happy
```

I tried the following piece of code but I'm getting an error :

```php
$tracks = Track::whereIn('id', function ( $query ) {
    $query->select('id')->from('tracks')->groupBy('track_name')->havingRaw('count(*) > 1');
})->paginate(20);
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'table.tracks.id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from
>   `tracks` where `id` in (select `id` from `tracks` group by
>   `track_name` having count(*) > 1))

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended but you should try

Remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from phpmyadmin

- Open phpmyadmin & select localhost
- Click on menu Variables & scroll down for sql mode
- Click on edit button to change the values & remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY & click on save.

Or you can run following query :

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: I have already checked this part and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not in the sql_mode list